# Python: use of same IV for encryption and decryption in AES

Tags: python, encryption, aes, initialization-vector

I struggle to understand the correct use of an IV (Initialization Vector) when encrypting data in AES.

Precisely, I'm not sure where to store my randomly generated IV: in my script, the data will be encrypted, then saved to a file, then the program will terminate. During the next session, the previously saved data must be decrypted. If my understanding of IVs is correct, I have to use the same IV for decryption as for encryption (but another random-IV for every single encryption process).
Thus, I have to store the IV somewhere - some people recommend prepending it to the encrypted data, but if I get it right that won't work in my case, because I need the IV *in order* to be able to decrypt it.

Is this correct or did I misunderstand something? I want to avoid saving the encrypted/hashed key and the IV (even if hashed itself) inside some unencrypted plain-text-settings-file or something.

Comment: *"some people recommend prepending it to the encrypted data, but if I get it right that won't work in my case"* - I think the error is here. That's exactly why it has to work. You're probably forgot to read the IV from the front of the ciphertext and skip it for decryption.

Comment: I think that's the point. I assumed the IV would be integrated inside the ciphertext - which is not the case, as you write: it is apparently prepended **after** the ciphertext is generated and can then be read (and split) in case of decryption.  The file type the whole thing is saved to is apparently not changed (txt or xml for example), which makes reading the IV easy. I was confused by the .enc file type I encountered in the tutorial I read. I thought that reading an .enc file before decrypting it would be impossible.

Answer (score 1):

The IV itself is not sensitive data; its just used to scramble the state of the first cipher-text block and the scrambling is not recoverable from the IV itself (the key adds in the "secret" factor).

For "proper" chaining modes the IV is separate from the cipher text (you need the initial IV for both encryption and decryption) and must be stored separately and passed separately to the crypto library API. After encryption you can store the IV however you like - just don't lose it ;).

You can certainly "prepend" / "append" to the cipher text so you only have to store a single blob of data - but you'll just have to split it off prior to decryption as that is what the API will expect.

The "unproper" way to do an IV (e.g. if your crypto library API doesn't have native IV support, but does support chaining) is just to prepend a single block of random data to the plaintext before encrypting it. In this case there isn't any IV to store separately - you simply encrypt the entire IV+message binary pair - and then you simply delete the first block of data after decrypting it. The "random data" you prepend has the same constraints as a real IV (don't reuse the same random data with the same key, etc).

The two approaches are semantically different at the API level, but the effect on the actual encryption is the same (scamble the first block of real payload unpredictably).

In terms of how the IV is used - there are many possible schemes. See the wikipedia article on block chaining here for a convenient picture showing how the IV can be used in various chaining modes when it is really store separately.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation

Comment: A link-only answer is not an answer.

Comment: Thank you! I thus need to solve my storage problem somehow, can you explain the "encryption paradox" I described above? E.g., that some people recommend saving the IV in the encrypted data, which in my point of view makes decoding the whole thing impossible: after restarting the script, the required IV is encrypted after all, but needed for decryption... Which other location is therefor recommendable for saving the IV?
EDIT: ah, I missed @Artjom B.'s comment. I think he figured out my misunderstanding.

Comment: Extended the answer so it wasn't just a link.

Comment: An IV shouldn't be stored seperately, there is no need, it isn't private information.

Comment: That's just a software design choice on the application side; you can safely store it where ever your application desires. The most sane design would certainly just prepend it to the encrypted stream (so it's immediately available to the decryption API call without having to seek across disk or wait until the end of the stream to start decryption), but it's not the only way to do it.